# User is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreateTopic on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I wanted to monitor certain parameters (TotalErrorRate and Latency) with CloudWatch and I wanted a "Simple Notification Service" (SNS) to send me an email, when an (cloudWatch) alarm is thrown:

```
EscalationTopic:
  Type: "AWS::SNS::Topic"
  Properties:
    DisplayName: My Monitoring
    Subscription:
      - Endpoint: !Ref EmailForNotification
        Protocol: email

EscalationTopicEmailSubscriber:
  Type: "AWS::SNS::Subscription"
  Properties:
    Endpoint: !Ref EmailForNotification
    Protocol: email
    TopicArn: !Ref EscalationTopic
```

But I get this error:
`User is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreateTopic on resource(Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AuthorizationError` (see screenshot)
[image]

What I did to solve it, is creating a topicPolicy:

```
   SNSTopicPolicy:
     Type: 'AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy'
     Properties:
       Topics:
         - !Ref EscalationTopic
       PolicyDocument:
         Version: '2012-10-17'
         Statement:
           - Effect: Allow
             Action: 'sns:CreateTopic'
             Resource: !Ref EscalationTopic
             Principal:
               AWS: '*'
```

But the problem still persists.

EDIT:
In the SNS console, I could manually create a new topic. Shouldn't it mean that I got the permission in order to createTopic?

Comment: Looks like your IAM user does not have enough privileges. Ask account admin to give you the ability to create topics.

Comment: @klubi In the SNS console, I could manually create a new topic. Shouldn't it mean that I got the permission in order to createTopic?

Comment: @thadeuszlay Did you solve this one? I am facing same problem. I have `AmazonSNSFullAccess` permission along with a few others. I can do all SNS actions in the console but when I try programmatically (like publish) I get an authorization error. 

`com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.AuthorizationErrorException: User: arn:aws:iam::*:user/* is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource: arn:aws:sns:**:app/GCM/* with an explicit deny (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AuthorizationError; Request ID: *)`

Comment: @SuryavelTR I'm facing exactly the same issue as yours. I have `AmazonSNSFullAccess` and I'm able to do all actions from AWS Console UI, but nothing from AWS CLI or SDK/Programmatically. Did you get a solution to your problem?

Comment: @miiiii Yes. For Android, I had to provide `CredentialsProvider` in `aws-configuration.json` to make it work. 

https://gist.github.com/xvelx/767c4f44ee3f1e169a0f9769a8e52f2c

Similarly, I had to do similar configuration at server side so my API can publish the notification. I don't remember what I did. I will check if I have old project still with me.

Comment: @SuryavelTR Thank you so much for responding to my comment, but in my case, it was working without any such configuration since the creation of the account, but all of sudden, one day it started giving me the error `403` when used via SDKs & `An error occurred (AuthorizationError)` when used via CLI. But the AWS Console UI is still working. And same happened to other colleagues' accounts as well. The AWS admin hasn't change any permission in between & my account has `AmazonSNSFullAccess`  permission. I don't get the root cause yet. :(

Comment: @SuryavelTR I don't think it's a credential provider problem for me as I can see the output of `aws sts get-caller-identity` resembles the Account ID/User ID very correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with Amazon SES. Apparently my "AmazonSESFullAccess" permission wasn't enough and I solved it by adding the "AmazonSNSFullAccess" permission to my IAM user at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/users/MY_IAM_USER_NAME_GOES_HERE

Answer (score 0):

The error message states the problem quite accurately. The credentials used to create the CloudFormation stack (presumably your login credentials unless you specified a Role during stack creation) is not authorized to create an Amazon SNS topic.

You should look at the permissions associated with your IAM User and add the necessary permissions.

Adding an SNS Topic Policy will have no impact because it is used to give SNS a set of permissions, whereas you need permissions to create the Topic itself.

Comment: In the SNS console, I could manually create a new topic. Shouldn't it mean that I got the permission in order to createTopic?

Comment: I wonder if the problem is related to the Subscriptions associated with the Topic? Try creating a very minimal stack with just `AWS::SNS::Topic` but without the `Subscription` sub-section. If that works, add back `Subscription` and see whether it gives an error. Start small, try for success, then put things back until you discover the problem.