# How can I configure the topic name when using MassTransit SQS?

Tags: amazon-sqs, masstransit

I use MassTransit SQS. I found out, when [publishing a message](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#publish), this problem occurs:

[User is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreateTopic on resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948006/user-is-not-authorized-to-perform-snscreatetopic-on-resource)

So I need rights to create topics.

I solved it by asking the admin to extend rights. This works and topics can be created. However, it seems that the topic names are automatically generated based on the class names. Can I modify this behaviour programmatically (so by giving a self described topic name).

This can be useful for creating a FIFO topic (which needs to have a name ending with .fifo).

**Update**

I am now familiar with [formatting](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/message.html#message-type-entity-name-formatting) (thanks for telling me Chris) with `SetEntityName`.

But my problem seems to be really fifo specific.

This works:

```
                cfg.Message<CustomerUpdate>(x =>
                {
                    x.SetEntityName("customerupdate");
                });
```

but this does not work:

```
                cfg.Message<CustomerUpdate>(x =>
                {
                    x.SetEntityName("customerupdate.fifo");
                });
```

It results in an exception with is error message:

> Invalid parameter: Topic Name

of this type:

> Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.Model.InvalidParameterException

with this stacktrace:

```
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionStream(IRequestContext requestContext, IWebResponseData httpErrorResponse, HttpErrorResponseException exception, Stream responseStream)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.<HandleExceptionAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.<HandleAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<ProcessExceptionAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.<InvokeAsync>d__7`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__10`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__9`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.<InvokeAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Contexts.TopicCache.<CreateMissingTopic>d__9.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Contexts.TopicCache.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<<Get>b__0>d.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
GreenPipes.Caching.Internals.PendingValue`2.<CreateValue>d__6.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.<Declare>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.<ConfigureTopology>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<GreenPipes-IFilter<MassTransit-AmazonSqsTransport-ClientContext>-Send>b__0>d.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
GreenPipes.PipeExtensions.<OneTimeSetup>d__2`1.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Pipeline.ConfigureTopologyFilter`1.<GreenPipes-IFilter<MassTransit-AmazonSqsTransport-ClientContext>-Send>d__3.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport.Transport.TopicSendTransport.SendPipe`1.<Send>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource<TContext>-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource<TContext>-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
GreenPipes.Agents.PipeContextSupervisor`1.<GreenPipes-IPipeContextSource<TContext>-Send>d__7.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()<PublishAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in Publisher.cs: line: 18
```

Here is my code

```
    public static void UseMassTransit(this IServiceCollection services, MassTransitConfiguration massTransitConfiguration)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<CustomerChangeConsumer>();
            x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host(massTransitConfiguration.Host, h =>
                {
                    h.AccessKey(massTransitConfiguration.AccessKey);
                    h.SecretKey(massTransitConfiguration.SecretKey);

                    h.EnableScopedTopics();
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("CustomerChangeConsumer",
                    configurator =>
                    {
                        configurator.ConfigureConsumer<CustomerChangeConsumer>(context);
                    });

                cfg.Message<CustomerUpdate>(x =>
                {
                    // This causes the exception when publishing:
                    x.SetEntityName("customerupdate.fifo");
                    // But this works. No issues when publishing
                    //x.SetEntityName("customerupdate");
                });
            });
        });
        
        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [configure the message topology](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/message.html) to specify the entity name formatting.

For instance, to change the topic name for the *OrderSubmitted* event:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAmazonSqs(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Message<OrderSubmitted>(x =>
    {
        x.SetEntityName("order-submitted.fifo");
    });

    cfg.Publish<OrderSubmitted>(x =>
    {
        x.TopicAttributes["FifoTopic"] = "true";
    });
});
```

To set the `MessageGroupId` on publish, use:

```
await bus.Publish<OrderSubmitted>(message, x => x.SetGroupId("..."));
```

> I'm not 100% sure that survives Publish, vs. Send.

Comment: Thanks but this is not a full solution for me as the name needs to end with ".fifo". The fifo extension in the name is required/essential when using fifo topics. For other topics, your suggested solution works fine. If I use your solution, I get this error message when trying to publish a message: `Invalid parameter: Topic Name`. Do you know a solution for fifo topics too?

Comment: Can't you just `SetEntityName("order-submitted.fifo")`? You can also configure the topics using `cfg.Publish<OrderSubmitted>(x => ....)` for topic attributes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for telling me but `SetEntityName` really does not work for me. I updated my question to clarify more. I am not sure how to use `cfg.Publish<OrderSubmitted>(x => ....)` in this case as the x parameter does not have a `SetEntityName` method there.

Comment: Added the publish topology to add the attributes based on reading the SNS documentation.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have a new error message, which typically means that I am getting closer to solving the problem:  `Invalid parameter: The MessageGroupId parameter is required for FIFO topics` . Do you know where to set the `MessageGroupId`? Setting it as a topic attribute does not solve the problem.

Comment: You're able to configure all those settings via MassTransit – how Amazon uses them is probably worth reading their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I already googled for `MessageGroupId` and found this documentation too. It am pretty sure MassTransit can help me to configure the `MessageGroupId` but the best way to learn how to do that, is a good coding example. For RabbitMQ with MassTransit, there are enough. But for SQS with MassTransit, there are not enough. I hope someone on stackoverflow can provide such an example. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Solved in 7.1.5