# AWS SNS can publish data with aws cli but getting permission error in python script that uses boto3 client

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-sns

In python script that uses the boto3 client, I am getting an `AuthorizationError`... `User: arn:aws:iam::... is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreateTopic...because no identity-based policy allows the SNS:CreateTopic action` when publishing message to a sns topic. So I verified using `aws cli` using same AWS credentials/keys and it works fine.

What additional policy or permission needs to be set for the user?

Comment: No extra permissions needed. If the CLI can do it boto3 can do it. Which means the problem are your credentials, how you run the python script, from where, what environment variables, etc. Does `print(boto3.client("sts").get_caller_identity())` display the identical information to `aws sts get-caller-identity`?

Comment: I confirmed, it is same.

Comment: Then you may different regions set.

Comment: I thought that too so I hard-code just to eliminate this env variable issue. In python error message, I see this: `arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:...` and I did `echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` in terminal where I run the `aws cli` and they are same regions - `us-east-1`

Comment: Seems similar issue to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948006/user-is-not-authorized-to-perform-snscreatetopic-on-resource

Comment: Although I can run `aws sns publish ...` successfully, it failed when I do `aws sns list-topics` with a permission error `...is not authorized to perform: SNS:ListTopics on resource...`. So I suspect this permission needs to be added because maybe the boto3 client is trying to list the topics and return the topic_arn based on the topic name.

Comment: on cli you are publishing message but on boto3 you are creating topic `is not authorized to perform: SNS:CreateTopic..`?

Comment: so better to add your code and policy to make thing clear

Comment: the boto3 api only has `create_topic` to get the topic. If it exists, it will not create. In my case, the topic already exists so it should not return an error. This is the boto3 api doc - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/sns.html

Comment: So you need to add create permissions as well as boto3 already doing api call for create

Answer (score -1):

This is probably a limitation of boto3 client because it works fine for the same user creds when publishing message using the `aws cli`. Currently in boto3, there is only a `create_topic` to get the topic arn.  Note that, the topic already exists and it should just return the topic arn. Looks like internally, it tries to query the topics. So we added permission to list the topics but it still fail with the same permission error. Finally we added `CreateTopic` permissions to the policy and that fixed the problem.